# Underscore one-liner to transform a collection into object of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to find an underscore one-liner to transform a collection into a dictionary of dictionary for later quick access.

Example : transforming this

```
[
    {a:'prop1', b:'subProp1', c:'first' }, 
    {a:'prop1', b:'subProp2', c:'second'}, 
    {a:'prop2', b:'subProp1', c:'third'}, 
    {a:'prop2', b:'subProp2', c:'forth'}
]
```

into this

```
{
    prop1 : 
    { 
        subProp1 : {a:'prop1', b:'subProp1', c:'first' },
        subProp2 : {a:'prop1', b:'subProp2', c:'second'}
    },
    prop2 : 
    { 
        subProp1 : {a:'prop1', b:'subProp1', c:'third' },
        subProp2 : {a:'prop1', b:'subProp2', c:'forth'}
    }
}
```

I know it is quite easy using a loop, but i'm looking for a neat-looking solution that underscore could maybe provide.

I've tried with groupbBy and indexBy, but I would still require a loop somewhere, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Please don't ask the code outright. Show your try.

Comment: Look at [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [T.J Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) `_.reduce` did the trick :

```
_.reduce(collection, function (aggr, obj) {
                        aggr[obj.a] = aggr[obj.a] || {};
                        aggr[obj.a][obj.b] = obj;
                        return aggr;
                    }, {});
```

Comment: You have to return `aggr`. At least you do if you are using native `Array#reduce`, don't know about Underscore.